# How to access nested QStandardItems?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PYQT5, I made a tree which contain a nested
QStandardItem objects for example:

```
house = QStandardItem('house')
room = QStandardItem('room')
kitchen= QStandardItem('kitchen')

house.appendRow(room)
house.appendRow(kitchen)
```

I need to access the room and kitchen objects inside the house object and change their names in the tree instead of room or kitchen to anything else.
How can I do that?

Comment: [`item.child()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#child)

Comment: house.child()? what will it return? in the real example I don't know the indexes of the rows or the columns that contains room and kitchen.

Comment: If you want to access child items, you need to use `child()`. *How* access them, depends on your needs. If you need to *find* items, well: [`findItems()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#findItems).

Comment: I'm sorry for a lot of questions I'm just a beginner, I tried to use findItems() in this way  house.findItems('room') but it crashed, can you tell me how to use it?

Comment: Please read more carefully the link for `findItems()`: it's a method of QStandardItemModel, not QStandardItem: you have to use it on the model.

Comment: yes now it is solved.. thank you so much for helping me